# Updating model challenge in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

Attempting to do an update using Laravel 5.4 as I continue learning but I'm having issues and I think it has something to do with the route in the form action. The error is NotFoundHttpException and this is the content of the uri

http://127.0.0.1:8000/task/5/('/task/5')?_token=8GPlMCXCfD5714MgtNaxQ90K6p07QSG6nKVAHNz9&employee_id=Chris+Rocky&title=Medium+task+level+updated&description=Updating+challenge&priority=high&begin=2017-06-06&end=2017-06-13

Below's what I'm working with

In my web.php file, I have

```
Route::put('/task/{id}', 'TaskController@update');
```

In my TaskController file

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    /*$task = Task::find($id);

    $task->fill($request->all);*/

    dd($request);

    //return view('task.view', compact('task'));
}
```

And this what I have in my form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="PUT" action="('/task/{{$task->id}}')">
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, unfortunately i haven't been able to pin it down after 3 days. How do i fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `('` and `')` in `action="('/task/{{$task->id}}')"`?

Comment: This works 'action='/task/{{$task->id}}'' but I don't get the dd($request). Instead i get redirected to the view page '(Route::get('/task/{id}', 'TaskController@show'))'

Comment: Base on the uri produced `task/5/('/task/5')` it seems that you are calling get method which is `task/5`

Comment: Maybe you need to rename your action put method that will not conflict to your get method.

Comment: I could change it to **Route::put('/task/update', TaskController@update** and **action='/task/update'** but that will return an error since the id is absent. How do i include the id in my action?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Getting the **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** after changing route to **Route::put('/task/{id}/update', 'TaskController@update')** and action to **action='/tasks/{{$task->id}}/update'** Looks like I will have to raise a seperate question for that now or do you have an idea on this?

Comment: Maybe my answer can help you to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From laravel 5.4 documentation, HTML forms can't make PUT, PATCH, or DELETE requests, you will need to add a hidden _method field to spoof these HTTP verbs. So i included the helper in my form, changed the form method to POST and kept the action the same as well as the route

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="PUT" action="('/task/{{$task->id}}')">
{{ csrf_field() }}
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to right your route web.php like this.

```
Route::put('/task', [
        'uses' => 'TaskController@update',
        'as' => 'task.update'
    ]);
```

and in your form you can call your route using `as` which mean alias.

Ex.

```
<form action="{{ route('task.update', ['id' => $task->id]) }}" method="put">
```

Comment: thanks but I'm still getting the same error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: You get `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` because in the form field you're using different Method (Eg. Get, Post, Put) in your `route.php`